# AndroidManifest.xml file missing when creating an android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, new-project

I tried to open an android project  File>New>Project>Android Application Project ... and here is my package explorer and the error that I have ..

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/rLLAkz.png]

What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the project explorer? Click on your project and press F5 to refresh. Additionally, go to "Project" in the menu bar and select "Clean"